# how to know if the current user follows another in django-friendship

Tags: python, django

Friends, I am using django-friendship to implement user follows in my application. I am trying to figure out how to know if the currently logged in user follows another or not. I am using a custom function in my models.py for the purpose.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    designation= models.CharField(max_length=32,choices=DESIGNATION,default="student", null=True)
    faculty = models.CharField(max_length=32,choices=FACULTIES, default="bridge", null=True)
    rep = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    scripts_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    # find out if the user is followed by current user
    def is_followed(self,*args):
    follows = Follow.objects.follows(self.user,*args)
    if follows:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and my template

```
{% for u in users %}
   {% if not u.userprofile.is_followed request.user %}
       <a href="{% url 'follow' u.username %}">Follow</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where am I going wrong? Help me out friends.

Comment: Can you show your `Follow` model

Comment: this Follow model is from django-friendship package. and it's got a follows() method to determine if a user is following another: Follow.objects.follows(follower,followee)

Comment: did you try your function in the shell by passing in the same user object?

Comment: It is working as expected in the shell but there is a template error. it doesn't recognize the     request.user     argument. I googled it and found that i needed to create a custom template tag. I know the basics of creating templatetags but can't figure out how to implement the above in a custom template tag and how to use it in templates.